# Rails, writing module. Where is to store setting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a behavior for models.

I'd like to include like this:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :blocks
    include Staticizable
    check_children :blocks #here name of children model to check
    ...
end
```

The behavior looks like:

```
module Staticizable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    module ClassMethods
        def check_children child
            self.child_model = child #where is to store model name to check?
        end
    end

    def was_staticized
        (DateTime.now - self.staticized_date.to_datetime).to_i
    end

    def staticized?
        if @child_model.present?
            ap self.send(@child_model)
        else
            if staticize_period > was_staticized
                true
            else
                false
            end
        end
    end

    def staticized
        self.staticized_date = DateTime.now
        save
    end
end
```

So I need to know where I can store model name to check children. And what is the right way to do things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer, not sure that is the best way, if no, let me know, please:

```
module Staticizable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        class << self;
            attr_accessor :has_child_custom
        end
    end

    module ClassMethods
        def check_children child
            self.has_child_custom = child
        end
    end

    def was_staticized
        unless staticized_date
            return false
        end
        (DateTime.now - self.staticized_date.to_datetime).to_i
    end

    def staticized?
        if self.class.has_child_custom.present?
            self.send(self.class.has_child_custom).each do |child|
                unless child.staticized?
                    return false
                end
            end
        else
            if self.staticize_period > was_staticized
                true
            else
                false
            end
        end

    end

    def staticized
        self.staticized_date = DateTime.now
        save
    end

end
```

Also I've created a file in /config/initializers with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Staticizable
```

And set it up in model with:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
    check_children :blocks
    ...
end
```